# Angular ng-submit action dependent on the button clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, form-submit

I'm using `ng-submit` (because of it being keyboard-friendly) and it works fine for forms having a single button. With multiple buttons, I created this funny construct

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
   ...
   <button ng-if=... ng-click="setAction('create')"...>create</button>
   <button ng-if=... ng-click="setAction('update')"...>update</button>
   <button ng-if=... ng-click="setAction('delete')"...>delete</button>
</form>
```

together with something like

```
var action;
$scope.setAction = function(a) {
    action = a;
}
$scope.submit = function() {
    var a = action || findTheDefaultAction();
    action = "";
    return myActions[a]();
};
```

and it works, but I find it very ugly:

- it relies on `ng-click` being called before `ng-submit`
- it's verbose and non-declarative
- it needs `findTheDefaultAction` which repeats the logic in the `ng-if` conditions.

Is there a better way?

Comment: are you wanting the enter key to fire off the correct button action as well? Have you tried on focus setting the action on corresponding button, then if user hits enter, the action will be already set?

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Yes, the enter key must work - firing the first visible button seems to be fine. And yes, there are multiple buttons visible sometimes.